# To hope something would or would not happen

Tags: grammar, words

I hope you did not experience anything as sad today.

今日そんな悲しさをなければと希望してます。

今日そんな悲しいことがなければといいな。

今日そんな悲しさをなかったらといいな。

今日そんな悲しいことがなかったと希望してます。

Are any of these close to what I am trying to say?
To give context I found a mikan ice cream today and was really happy but it turned out to be really bad. So I was talking with a girl and wanted to say that I hoped nothing as said has happened to her. Is there maybe a better way of saying this than I am trying to use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: for one thing, be careful which version you use, because 悲しさ means "sadness", it's the word representing the internal emotion, and in Japanese I don't think it makes any sense to talk about "not having it"... in my experience, when さ  is attached to an adjective and discussed, it's because that quality has already been noticed... Sorry, not sure if I'm being clear here... 

Also which mikan ice cream was it, so I can avoid it? :P

Comment: it makes perfect sense, thank you for explaining. I believe it was called ガツン、truly disappointing taste.

Comment: i will be wary of it. Sorry I couldn't help with your question much. I think this sort of sentiment might be unusual to actually express in Japanese. I'm waiting for a native to weigh in on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Caution**: It is easy to "translate" things into Japanese, but whether or not that translated phrase/sentence would actually be uttered/written by a native Japanese speaker somewhere is a totally different matter.

First, my comment on each of your attempts.

> 今日{きょう}そんな悲{かな}しさ**を**なければと希望{きぼう}してます。

Ungrammatical for using 「を」.  「ない」 is an adjective, so you cannot use an 「を」 right in front of it.

> 今日そんな悲しいことがなければ**と**いいな。

Ungrammatical for using 「と」 there.  You can say 「ない**と**いい」, but not 「なければ**と**いい」.  That 「と」 needs to be dropped.

> 今日そんな悲しさ**を**なかったらといいな。

Ungrammatical for the same reason as the first sentence.  You might want to review the particle 「を」.  You may have been over-using it.

> 今日そんな悲しいことがなかったと希望してます。

Looks pretty good as far as grammar.  We just do not use 「希望する」 nearly as often as English-speakers use "to hope".  Remember if you can that 「希望する」is a bigger word than "to hope".

My own TL's:

「こんな悲しい出来事{できごと}が、今日{きょう}君{きみ}には起{お}こらなかったことを願{ねが}ってる。」

「こんな悲しいことが、今日、少{すく}なくとも君には起きなかったことを願ってる。」

「こんな悲しい出来事が、今日君にはなかったことを祈{いの}って・・」

Comment: This is golden, thank you so much for pointing out my mistakes and then providing the proper way of saying what I wanted to convey. 

The particles are my nemesis, I just can never really grasp them. I think I've ignored my lack of basic knowledge for far too long.

Comment: @JakeOlesniewicz don't forget to accept l'électeur's answer if it solves your question to your satisfaction. Unless you're waiting for other people to weigh in?

Comment: @ericfromabeno Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @l'électeur is the "hope" represented by 希望 closer to the sense of longing, or yearning? It kind of feels like maybe it's closer to those kinds of feelings, since in English those synonyms for "hope" are also rarely used...